# wp-config.php cannot be created by wordpress setup

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

The guide says ” The WordPress setup process will create a wp-config.php file for you based on the information you provide.
but it didn't create it and i got error occurred while trying to connect to the database !
should i create a wp-config.php file by myself and provide the informations of my database using the text editor?

i remind you that am using WP for the first time and am trying to work just in localhost, i already create a virtual host

thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Yes you can create it yourself. There should be a `wp-config-sample.php` file in the root directory. Copy that and name it `wp-config.php` and put your own details in there and it should work. There's nothing too fancy that gets automatically added besides your personal DB/salt information.

Comment: Ye you could create it as Xhynk says. My only concern would be that if your install didn't create that, are there any other missing files or problems with the set up. Check your permissions (maybe the install didn't have permission to update the file after it was created or something like that.

Comment: You could also try asking on the [WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com) - Stack Overflow is for programming questions, that site is more suited to questions about WordPress administration, server configuration, etc.

Comment: first of all tank you for your support, as you said @Xhynk, i create  wp-config.php then i provide the informations of my database but i receive "The file 'wp-config.php' already exists. If you need to reset any of the configuration items in this file, please delete it first. You may try installing now."